# how to zero with size 3D plot of two variable function

Tags: matlab-figure

I want to draw a two variable function plot using octave. First of all, I'm going to use the meshgrid function to create the x,t axis, and then I'm going to create a u(x,t), and the form I want is a summing form. So I'm going to use the for loof, and I need to reset this function to sum=0. I don't know how to reset it to zero.  I wrote down my code.

```
 clear;
 [x,t] = meshgrid(0:0.2:pi);                                
 sum=0;
 for n=1:5
   sum+=(1/n^2)*sin(n*pi/2)*exp(-1.6352*n^2*pi^2*t/100^2)*sin(n*pi*x/100)/pi^2;

 end


 surf(x,t,sum)

xlabel('x');
ylabel('t');
zlabel('solution');
```

It seems strange for initating sum=0 since sum variable is multivariable function with x,t.

how to plot this?